# messagebox appeared second time

Tags: vb.net, textbox

In my code, when `TextBox3` does not have any value, it must show a notice in a `MsgBox` to enter a value in `TextBox1`

But when I run it the `MsgBox`notice appears twice in the screen when it should show only once.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox3.Text = Nothing Then
        TextBox1.Clear()
        MsgBox("Enter Number to Textbox1")
    Else
        Dim digit As Integer = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
        If TextBox1.TextLength = digit Then
            Dim fields() As String = ListBox1.Text.Split(";")
            Dim idx As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text)
            If idx <> -1 Then
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = idx
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(0))
                ListBox2.Items.Add(Now() + Space(1) + ListBox1.Text.Substring(0, 13))
                PrintDocument1.Print()
            Else
                TextBox1.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your questions have answers. please do not forget to upvote answers that have helped you, and to accept an answer.

Comment: @3vts: In future, please do not **add** useless fluff like "Help is appreciated", "thanks in advance", or "have a nice day". Instead (if already editing the post) **remove** those in accordance with [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts); they should never be deliberately included in a post.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue here is that the event handler gets triggered another time because clearing the textbox1 equals the textbox1_changed event handler to go of. You could as well just disable the textbox till the textbox3 is not nothing anymore.
or a quick solution would be aswell

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
If not TextBox1.Text = Nothing AndAlso TextBox3.text = Nothing Then
    TextBox1.Clear()
    MsgBox("Enter Number to Textbox1")
.............
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event. Textchanged triggers when you clear the textbox as well resulting in two messageboxes.

Use `LostFocus` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

```
Public Class Form1
            Dim message as boolean = true    
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
            If TextBox3.Text = Nothing Then
            If message Then 'show the message as true
            message = False 'set the message false for textbox_changed not appear again
            Textbox1.Clear()
            message = True 'set the message true for next time textbox change appear again
            MsgBox("Enter Number to Textbox3")
    End If
                    Else
                        Dim digit As Integer = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
                        If TextBox1.TextLength = digit Then
                            Dim fields() As String = ListBox1.Text.Split(";")
                            Dim idx As Integer = ListBox1.FindString(TextBox1.Text)
                            If idx <> -1 Then
                                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = idx
                                ListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(fields(0))
                                ListBox2.Items.Add(Now() + Space(1) + ListBox1.Text.Substring(0, 13))
                                PrintDocument1.Print()
                            Else
                                TextBox1.Clear()
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End Sub
```